# Чому префікс су- втратив продуктивність?

Tags: словотворення, префікс

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0) каже, що приросток *су-* втратив продуктивність. Чому ми більше не утворюємо слів зі цим приростком? І чи знаємо ми, яке значення давало додавання цього приростку?

> До непродуктивних належать також нерегулярні афікси, що втратили здатність і відтворюватися в словах, і утворювати похідні слова. Непродуктивними в сучасній українській мові є такі афікси: 1) префікси па- (пасинок), пра- (прадід), су- (супіски)', 2) суфікси: -в-о (місиво, пиво), -ев-а (королева), -ай (шахрай), -тель із значенням конкретних предметів (глушитель), -ичі, -ічі у прислівниках (двічі, тричі), -ень (лежень), -ак (вожак), -ич (погонич), -ир (проводир).

Comment: По-моєму (і [тут](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine44-12.pdf) пишуть), це про певну спільність: «спільно з, разом», а також «подібно до» і «цільним шматком». Як-от _сузір'я_ (об'єднання зірок), _сумірний_ (що мір. такою ж мірою), _супутник_, _суглоб_, _сувій_, _суглинок_, _сукупний_ тощо. Є відповідником (можливо, сучаснішому) префіксу _спів-_ (_співмірний_, _співробітник_, _співавтор_, _співрозмовник_, _співпрацювати_, _співмешканець_), а також лат. _con-_ (_constellation_) та _co-_ (_cooperate_) і (частково рос.) _со-_ (_сотрудник_, _созвездие_). Чому непродуктивний — не знаю.

Comment: @Sasha я теж думав про схожість зі *спів-*.